# How can we do User acceptance testing Manually?

Tags: manual-testing, regression-testing, qa-role, user-acceptance-testing

General User acceptance testing test cases of any application or software.
Test cases of user acceptance testing like some of below:

- Add tab functionality in a form
- Shortcut keys of saving any form

How to check user acceptance testing in any application or form? How to check it?

EDIT PART:
Just wanted to know what should be in general test scenarios of User acceptance testing. I am listing some below:
1. Tabbing functionality in a form
2. Shortcuts in applications

Like above two, what are others??????

Comment: It would good if you add some description around this.

Comment: What are you asking? Please add some detail, it will facilitate answering a lot!

Comment: I am voting to close this because it is very broad, kind of like asking "How do I program in Java?" or "How do I write a web page?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User acceptance testing, by definition, must always be done manually.  This is the last step of testing where end users verify that the software functions the way that they expect it to, and lay out any deficiencies prior to the software being put into production (preferably).

If you are currently automating UAT, it isn't UAT but is rather a form of regression testing.  An excellent definition of UAT is:

> The acceptance test is a set of independent tests performed by the customer.  The user defines acceptance criteria with the assistance of the QA organization

While bare, this definition (provided by a training manual from Skill Focused Training) is about a succinct as it gets.

To answer your question more specifically:

- The user or client organization should define expectations early on.  This should be the guide to software design and development to begin with
- During development, QA should be ensuring that any actionable pieces of the design are exercised.  This process continues with each major change.
- After the software is in a beta state or later, the customer/client should be allowed to exercise the software on their own and ensure that their expectations are met based on the initial definitions.
- Rework can happen here, during beta, based on client feedback

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty general QA question, so the answer will be more general ...

1. Basically you need to look over the requirements fro that form in order to create the user acceptance testing scenarios. In case you have them you can parse them and create scenarios that cover all the requirements / criteria.
2. If you do not have any requirements, you should talk with your product owner, scrum master or anyone in your company that wanted this forms implemented into the product.
3. Other than that, a usual form should some input fields and a submit button. You should test those can be seen correctly in all major browsers (or the one that the product targets).

You should also test that what you submit in the form has an effect in your product / application.

I hope this answer!